# can we call a webservice when app is not open and remote notification come from beacon?

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, ibeacon

I just want to know can we call a web service in the background when the app is not open and remote notification come from beacon? if yes then how?
web service takes time around 1-2 minutes to execute.
please help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can call web service when App is in backgound, by checking App **background** **fetch** from **capabilities**. 
but App should be running and can be in background.
[see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsEAC.png)

Comment: but if app is in suspended state then? @ajjjjjjjj

Comment: suspended  :The app is in the background but is not executing code. The system moves apps to this state automatically and does not notify them before doing so. While suspended, an app remains in memory but does not execute any code.
When a low-memory condition occurs, the system may purge suspended apps without notice to make more space for the foreground app.

Comment: so when notification is not silent then we cannot do this? user must have to come forground, m i right? @ajjjjjjjj

Comment: Can we discuss full scenario. its not enough. may be then can give better solution

Comment: to execute the code. on foreground or background But cannot on suspended state.

Comment: my app is not open and I get the notification , in this scnario how can I call a web service in background? @ajjjjjjjj

Comment: Impossible, You can call web service  at max on notification click App launch.